# Open Directory network user last logon time

Tags: bash, open-directory

I am looking for a bash command to query my LDAPv3 server from the client side in order to find the current user's last logon time.

Answer (score 1):

Will this do the job for you?

```
ldapsearch -LLL -x -h <hostaddr> -Z -D cn=admin,o=local -W  "(&(objectclass=Person))" logintime
```

Comment: We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions